# Not able to use await in then block to call another API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am calling one API.in the then section of API call, i am calling another API. the output of first API will be passed to another API.

```
await axios
  .post(process.env + '/certificates/upload', {
      "name": "Shruti"
    }
  })
.then((response: any) => {
      filenames = JSON.stringify(response.data.office);

      axios // Not able to write async here
        .patch(process.env + "/certificates/", {
          file: filenames
        })
        .then(function(response: any) {
          alert(' Record updated successfully');
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          alert('Error in updating the record');
        });
```

I am not able to use `await` in second API call. Where should I put `async` to use `await` in second API call? first call is working properly. also Is there any better way to call consecutive API and Passing output of first call to second.

Comment: you dont need to use .then when using await instead you can write something similar too

let response = await axios
             .post(process.env+ '/certificates/upload',{"name":"Shruti"}
             })

let filenames = JSON.stringify(response.data.office);
               
let response = await axios.patch(process.env+"/certificates/", {
                     file: filenames 
               })

Comment: Relevant: [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815)

Comment: so even if I dont use await in second call it will always work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the function that contains the statement you wish to `await`. Add `async` to the beginning of that function.

More generally, avoid mixing `async`/`await` with chained `.then`/`.catch`.

I think this is what you want:

```js
try {
    let response1 = await axios.post(
        process.env + '/certificates/upload',
        { name: "Shruti" }
    )
    let filenames = JSON.stringify(response1.data.office)

    await axios.patch(
        process.env + "/certificates/",
        { file: filenames }
    )

    alert(`Update succeeded`)

} catch( error ) {
    alert(`Update failed`)
}
```